# How to un wrap the key using get api in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have generated PPK using `ssh-keygen -t rsa` in my VM and upload private key in the Azure Key Vault - Key.
Now I want to retrieve the private key using get apis,  I am following below links.

1. Retrieved token from `curl 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net' -H Metadata:true -s`
2. Retrieved key detail as below ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getkey/getkey )

Request

```
GET /keys/sftp/ec836864d1844c9082396e8f50344e68?api-version=7.1 HTTP/1.1
Host: test-poc-kv-01.vault.azure.net
Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN
POST /keys/sftp/ec836864d1844c9082396e8f50344e68/unwrapKey?api-version=7.1 HTTP/1.1
Host: test-poc-kv-01.vault.azure.net
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <MY_TOKEN>
Content-Length: 383
```

Response :

```
    {
    "key": {
        "kid": "https://test-poc-kv-01.vault.azure.net/keys/sftp/ec836864d1844c9082396e8f50344e68",
        "kty": "RSA",
        "key_ops": [
            "sign",
            "verify",
            "wrapKey",
            "unwrapKey",
            "encrypt",
            "decrypt"
        ],
        "n": "z4LvtDZMrD7PR8EZkWcfexJDkMsak8slsA3H-byjMw0sEr-S0zfMNYS9tBHwsSW77npIN-WJoKvajz9lCvHMJAgEhSNZVKJdokchXNXVDetA_o6HMARX4VdP02MpFioZ4t630PZqVl1nSIqub_bZ-Oa1aTWGt-VpjPy_FTj-PY1hdaz_1YVbpnTg-FOc77kisUfVMlOVSWVxTdccMOe1rlqh3zEQud_le5X8iDTeTP46tkcQIWbDzeTXknYgh4y0Lh3p1yq3Q4Y6sZbgE_EG33vNt4agB4aS5nEL41KPH_EC440zlmUcChTK1mfebHjctWakyBNtunTLai6-zR-BjjQ",
        "e": "AQAB"
    },
    "attributes": {
        "enabled": true,
        "created": 1607544986,
        "updated": 1607544986,
        "recoveryLevel": "Recoverable",
        "recoverableDays": 90
    }
}
```

3. Now when I try to unwrap key, I am getting error response

Request :

```
POST /keys/sftp/ec836864d1844c9082396e8f50344e68/unwrapKey?api-version=7.1 HTTP/1.1
Host: test-poc-kv-01.vault.azure.net
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <MY_TOKEN>
Content-Length: 381

{
  "alg": "RSA1_5",
  "value": "z4LvtZMrD7PR8EZkWcfexJDkMsak8slsA3H-byjMw0sEr-S0zfMNYS9tBHwsSW77npIN-WJoKvajz9lCvHMJAgEhSNZVKJdokchXNXVDetA_o6HMARX4VdP02MpFioZ4t630PZqVl1nSIqub_bZ-Oa1aTWGt-VpjPy_FTj-PY1hdaz_1YVbpnTg-FOc77kisUfVMlOVSWVxTdccMOe1rlqh3zEQud_le5X8iDTeTP46tkcQIWbDzeTXknYgh4y0Lh3p1yq3Q4Y6sZbgE_EG33vNt4agB4aS5nEL41KPH_EC440zlmUcChTK1mfebHjctWakyBNtunTLai6-zR-BjjQ"
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadParameter",
        "message": "The parameter is incorrect.\r\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you encode `value` to base64?

Comment: No, I have added plain private key in the key.

Comment: I don't think this is doing what you think it is (I might be wrong).
1) A wrapped key must be symmetric
2) GetKey operation only returns the public portion of an asymmetric key.  If the key is symmetric, it is not released from the Key Vault.

Your unwrap operation request uses the key which was returned from the get key operation, which by definition is asymmetric, so it can't be unwrapped and therefore is an invalid parameter.